# JAXB Custom Validator

Tags: java, xml, validation, jaxb, xsd

I have a method like this:

```
private static <T> T readXML(final String file, final String schemaFile, final Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new EventHandler());
        final SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        final String directory = System.getProperty("schema.dir");
        unmarshaller.setSchema(schemaFactory.newSchema(new File(directory, schemaFile)));
        return clazz.cast(unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(directory, file)));
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(1);
    return null;
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
private static final Primitives primitives = readXML("primitives.xml", "primitives.xsd", Primitives.class);
```

My question is that is it possible to add custom validators to the unmarshaller?
What I mean is that lets say I have a complexType called Foo. And I want to make some validations on it which I can't describe in the xsd file, so I want to do something like this:

```
unmarshaller.setCustomValidator(Foo.class, new MyCustomValidator());
```

So MyCustomValidator will be called everytime JAXB reads a Foo.
Or if I can't describe some validations in the xsd file, than I have to validate the parsed classes after the JAXB reading finished?

Oh, btw... I generated the JAXB classes from xsd with xjc.

Comment: I said I want a cutom validator. schema.newValidator() validates against the xsd. I want to do some other validations than defined in the xsd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose if the validation rules can't bee described in the xsd, then it's kind of out of scope for JAXB. But if you devise a structure when you can get a custom validator object based on the class, you can add that logic at the end of your method to preserve its encapsulation quality.